# Использование Php кода в pug

Tags: php, html, pug

Есть кусок кода на pug

```
p.text-center Все права защищены &copy '<?= date('Y');?>'
```

Но компилируется php код закомментированным, кавычками обрамлял, результат тот же, в чем может быть проблема?

```
<p class="text-center">Все права защищены © "<!--?= date('Y');?-->"</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Нужно включить параметр short_open_tag
http://linux-notes.org/vklyuchit-vy-klyuchit-short_open_tag-v-php/

Или пишите код так:

```
p.text-center Все права защищены &copy '<php echo date('Y'); ?>'
```

Comment: Суть вопроса не в php и short tag, а в том, что "мопс" делает код php комментарием Все права защищены © <!--?php echo date('Y');?-->;

Answer (score 0):

Экранировать функции можно через `|` . Ниже привожу пример с функцией PHP:

```
  h1 FAQ

    .summury
        details
            summary Some text
            p
                | <?php md_cache()?>
```

Вышеприведенный код скомпилируется в:

```
   <h1>FAQ</h1>
   <div class="summury">
   <details>
       <summary>Some text</summary>
       <p><?php md_cache()?></p>
   <details>
```